# Is there a way for JavaFx application to notice a change in default printer

Tags: java, javafx, printing

```
javafx.print.Printer.getDefaultPrinter()
```

Always returns printer that was default when application started. Is there a way for application to notice that default printer was changed and use the new default printer without restarting the whole application?

Comment: Doesn't it change when the default system printer changes? That is, if you call this method again after changing the default printer in your OS configuration, does it return the old value or the new one? 
If it is indeed dynamic, you just have to call it right as you are meaning to print (assuming you do not need immediate reaction to the default system printer changing).

Comment: Actualy it does not. It still returns the old value. I even tested it with simple program, a cycle that calls the method every five seconds and outputs the default printer. It is outputing the same value over and over even if you change default printer in OS. If you stop the program and run it again it changes (if default printer in OS changed) but then it stays the same for whole run.